# Managing properly an array of results that is larger than the memory available at the GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

Having defined how to deal with errors:

```
static void HandleError( cudaError_t err,
                         const char *file,
                         int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),
                file, line );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))
```

Normally, to store our results in the array d_results, of  type double, of size N, that can be allocated in the GPU memory at once, we can manage to transfer the data from the device to the host like so:

```
    double *d_results;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_results,N*sizeof(double)));
//Launch our kernel to do some computations and store the results in d_results
.....
// and transfer our data from the device to the host
vector<double> results(N);
cudaMemcpy(results.data(),d_results,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

If the second line fails because there are not enough memory to store all the results at once. How can I manage to do the computations and transfer the results to the host properly? is mandatory to do the computation by batches? I rather to avoid a manual batching. What is the standard approach to manage this situation in CUDA?

Comment: Manual batching is probably the best option.  The only other general option would be to use host-mapped memory in CUDA, also referred to as zero-copy memory.  This allows host memory to be mapped directly into the memory space of the GPU, and accessed like GPU global memory.  However it will typically be quite slow for general-purpose access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batching is the best way to go. You can automate most of the batching process if you do something like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Allocate 4 Gb array on host
    const size_t N = 1 << 30;
    int * data = new int[N];

    // Allocate as much memory as will fit on GPU
    size_t total_mem, free_mem;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
    const size_t MB = 1 << 20;

    cudaError_t status;
    int *buffer;
    size_t buffer_size = free_mem;
    for(; buffer_size > MB; buffer_size -= MB) {
        status = cudaMalloc((void **)&buffer, buffer_size);
        if (status == cudaSuccess)
            break;
    }

    std::cout << "Allocated " << buffer_size << " bytes on GPU" << std::endl;

    // Loop through host source data in batches
    std::cout << N << " items require processing" << std::endl;
    size_t batchN = buffer_size / sizeof(int);
    size_t remainN = N;
    int * dp = data;
    std::cout << "Using batch size " << batchN << std::endl;

    for(; remainN > 0; remainN -= batchN) {
        batchN = (remainN < batchN) ? remainN : batchN;
        size_t worksize = batchN * sizeof(int);
        std::cout << "Processing batch of size " << batchN;
        std::cout << "," << remainN << " items remaining" << std::endl;
        cudaMemcpy(buffer, dp, worksize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemset(buffer, 0xff, worksize);
        cudaMemcpy(dp, buffer, worksize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        dp += batchN;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        assert(data[i] == 0xffffffff);
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

Which is basically

1. Allocate as much free memory as your device has
2. Iteratively process the input data to the gpu in buffer size chunks until everything is done

In the above code I have used cudaMemset as a proxy for a real kernel, but it gives you an idea of what is required. If you want to get fancier, you could use two buffers and streams (with registered/pinned host memory) and copy asynchronously to get compute/copy overlap which will improve the overall performance in non trivial cases.